# Rails field (type hash) and multiple checkboxes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox

I am using Rails (3.2.5 with ruby 1.9.3) and mongodb with mongoid. I'd like to give the user the option to check weekdays. Therefore I have a field with type hash in my controller:

```
field :wochentage, :type => Hash, default: {  :mo => 0,
                                            :di => 0,
                                            :mi => 0,
                                            :dn => 0,
                                            :fr => 0,
                                            :sa => 0,
                                            :so => 0
                                          }
```

The problem is that I cannot get this to work in the web form:

```
<% for d,v in @timetable.wochentage  %>
    <td><%= f.check_box :wochentage[d]%></td>
<% end %>
```

The error I get is:

> can't convert Symbol into Integer

Can anyone please point me to the right direction?
Thanks in advance,
Sven

OK, a little step further: with the fields_for form helper I got closer:

```
<%= f.fields_for :wochentage do |w| %>
      <td><%= w.check_box :mo %></td>
      <td><%= w.check_box :di %></td>
      <td><%= w.check_box(:mi, checked_value: "1", unchecked_value: "0") %></td>
      <td><%= w.check_box :dn %></td>
      <td><%= w.check_box :fr %></td>
      <td><%= w.check_box :sa %></td>
      <td><%= w.check_box :so %></td>
    <% end %>
```

With this code I can set the weekday. But it won't read it from the DB, if I want to edit it though it is stored correctly: `Wochentage: {"mo"=>"0", "di"=>"0", "mi"=>"1", "dn"=>"0", "fr"=>"0", "sa"=>"0", "so"=>"0"}`

In the edit form all checkboxes are unchecked. So how can I make the checkbox show up in the correct status?

Thanks,
S

Comment: Even if you answer your own question you still should accept it. It will mark question as answered an you will be awarded with nice bronze badge :)

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I was searching for a way to mark it as answered...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

OK, I got it:

```
<%= f.fields_for :wochentage do |w| %>
  <% @timetable.wochentage.each do |t,v| %>
    <td><%= w.check_box t, checked: (v == "1" ? "checked" : "") %></td>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

The funny thing: Normal check_box saves checked as true, unchecked as false. When you have multiple checkboxes for a field as hash the checkboxes save 1 for checked, 0 for unchecked.